# Reading all SIM setting

Tags: sim-card

Just out of curiosity I'd like to see all the settings on my SIM-card. And I'm not talking about an SMS stored on the card, or my phonebook. I'd like to see for example the Preferred PLMN list and Forbidden PLMN list.

I'd think you could get access to it with an API or smth, but I couldn't find it (yet).

Anyone got a clue how?

Comment: From within code? From an `adb shell`? From your Settings menu? If you're looking for a Java API then this is off-topic here as we don't cover development questions.

Comment: Doesn't really matter how I can access it. Anyway would be sufficient. :)